# Spring Boot 1.3.1.RELEASE "Using default security password"

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

During my Spring Boot 1.3.1.RELEASE application startup I noticed a following line in the log:

```
Using default security password: d60d96ca-1285-41c9-aed7-d5688af74688
```

What does it mean and how to fix it ?

I suspect I have some issues in the my application config:

Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

WebSecurityConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    @Value("${ok.client.publicKey}")
    private String okClientPublicKey;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off   
        http
        .headers().frameOptions().disable()
        .and().logout()
        .and().antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/index.html", "/home.html").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/"))
        .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
        .and().csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
        .and().addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        // @formatter:on
    }

    private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {
            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
                CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
                if (csrf != null) {
                    Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                    String token = csrf.getToken();
                    if (cookie == null || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                        cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                        cookie.setPath("/");
                        response.addCookie(cookie);
                    }
                }
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            }
        };
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(filter);
        registration.setOrder(-100);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("ok")
    ClientResources ok() {
        return new ClientResources();
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter() {
        CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
        List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        filters.add(ssoFilter(ok(), "/login/ok"));
        filter.setFilters(filters);
        return filter;
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResources client, String path) {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter clientFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(path);
        OAuth2RestTemplate clientTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);
        clientFilter.setRestTemplate(clientTemplate);
        OkUsersClient okUsersClient = new OkUsersClient(client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(), okClientPublicKey,
                client.getClient().getClientSecret(), clientTemplate);
        clientFilter.setTokenServices(new OkUserInfoTokenServices(okUsersClient, client.getClient().getClientId()));
        clientFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new UrlParameterAuthenticationHandler());
        return clientFilter;
    }

    class UrlParameterAuthenticationHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

        @Override
        protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(request, response);

            if (response.isCommitted()) {
                logger.debug("Response has already been committed. Unable to redirect to " + targetUrl);
                return;
            }

            String queryString = HttpUtils.removeParams(request.getQueryString(), "state", "code");
            targetUrl = !StringUtils.isEmpty(queryString) ? targetUrl + "?" + queryString : targetUrl;
            getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
        }

    }

    class ClientResources {

        private OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails client = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
        private ResourceServerProperties resource = new ResourceServerProperties();

        public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails getClient() {
            return client;
        }

        public ResourceServerProperties getResource() {
            return resource;
        }

    }

}
```

application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8443
  ssl:
    key-store: keystore.p12
    key-store-password: ***
    keyStoreType: PKCS12
    keyAlias: tomcat

spring:
  aop:
    proxy-target-class: true

ok:
  client:
    accessTokenUri: https://api.ok.ru/oauth/token.do
    userAuthorizationUri: https://connect.ok.ru/oauth/authorize
    clientId: ***
    clientSecret: ***
    publicKey: ***
    authenticationScheme: query
    clientAuthenticationScheme: form
  resource:
    userInfoUri: https://api.ok.ru/fb.do

logging:
    file: application.log
    level:
        org.springframework: INFO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Spring Security (you have, because of EnableOAuth2Client) in your project and don't specify a user and a password Spring Boot creates at least a secure password for you (you might want to read more in the [manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html))
)

> If Spring Security is on the classpath then web applications will be
> secure by default with ‘basic’ authentication on all HTTP endpoints.
> To add method-level security to a web application you can also add
> @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity with your desired settings. Additional
> information can be found in the Spring Security Reference.
>
> The default AuthenticationManager has a single user (‘user’ username
> and random password, printed at INFO level when the application starts
> up)
>
> Using default security password: 78fa095d-3f4c-48b1-ad50-e24c31d5cf35

You should set these values in [application.properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) to avoid it:

```
security.user.name=...
security.user.password=... 
security.user.role=...
```

Converted to your application.yml it will look like:

```
security:
    user:
        name: ...
        password: ...
        role: ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Right now I'm trying to understand why do I need to define such kind of user in case I have secured my application with an external OAuth2 provider ?

Comment: Why ? To prevent "open doors". There are many endpoints which need to be protected, because of this Spring Security sets this default user. The actuator endpoints for example need protection too.

Comment: @Marged Why should a user be needed to secure an endpoint? a user is needed to get the content of a secured endpoint, but not to secure it.

Comment: @YannicKlem Replace user with username. Some endpoints are security relevant and because of this you need to login. For that you need a username and password.

Comment: Of course but thats not the point of his question. He asks why there has to be a default user when using an external OAuth2 provider. The endpoints should be secured of course. But there is no need for the default user

Comment: This came clear after his comment, the question was - my impression - not clear about this. Obviously Spring Security does not recognize that another authsystem was defined. Perhaps they run in parallel